# One domain object 'filled' by several repositories

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I am new to DDD and need to clear some concept so that i can apply it on my project.

Basically, i have a domain object "Customer". CustomerRepository would return this domain object by referring the DAL.

The problem is that the DAL cannot provide all the information needed to 'fill' Customer domain object. Some information regarding the Customer will be acquired by some other external resource, maybe some other repository or a external web service.

Maybe i should divide my "Customer" domain object. But what if my business logic doesn't allow me to do so?

Also, is it only repository responsibility to return domain object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be responsibility of repository.

Storage is cheap nowadays. Maybe doubling that data would solve Your problems? E.g., if customer.firstname comes from data source #1 but customer.lastname comes from data source #2, You could just make sure that on customer registration customer.lastname is stored in data source #1 (+ procedure that would update already registered customers)?

Another thing - Your domain model shouldn't know about this problem. You should try to keep it unaware of technical problems. Otherwise - You will eventually lose isolation and end up with artificial domain objects that are coded there just to make it run.

Comment: +1. Don't compromise your domain Customer entity, otherwise you'll spread architectural polution throughout the domain model.  Keeping the model accurate is a core tenet of DDD.  Repository is the natural home for dealing with the problem.  Any reason why it can't access both storage locations (i.e. DAL + Web service/whatever)?

Comment: @sfinnie only reason there is - it might be technically hard and could impact performance heavily. apart from that - nothing wrong.

Comment: ok.  I'd still vote for keeping the Domain Entity complete from the point of view of the remainder of the domain.  You could potentially look at some "lazy load" type strategy for repo.  However I'd start simple first and only go there if you find you actually get performance issues.